# How to open jquery ui tabls by external(other links besides tab links) links

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I've used [jquery ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default) in my webpage. Everything is fine. But, I want that I can open the next tabbed pages by both of tab links and other links. But, I can't make it. I've tried at [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/er7Rc/2/) At every tabs, there are "Next" or "Previous" link by which I want to open next and previous tab relatively(just like the First Tab, Second Tab and Third Tab link). I've applied the same techniques as the tab links used at jquery ui:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third Tab</a></li>
</ul>
```

But, it won't work:

```
<a href="#tabs-1" class="left">Previous</a> 
<a href="#tabs-2" class="right">Next</a> 
<a href="#tabs-3" class="right">Next</a>
```

So, how can I open other tab pages by internal/external links too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have *forked* your example and made changes to it **[`here!`](http://jsfiddle.net/9j74g/4/)**

Setting the **`active`** tab by ***INDEX*** using `$("#tabs").tabs({ active: INDEX });` will allow you to navigate to any tab.

For example, also **[`here!`](http://jsfiddle.net/Q24PV/1/)**:

### **HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">First Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Second Tab</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1"><p>This is first tab!<p>
        <button class="btn-next">Next</button>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2"><p>This is second tab!<p>
        <button class="btn-prev">Previous</button>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### **JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    $(".btn-next").click(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 1 });
    });

    $(".btn-prev").click(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 0 });
    });

});
```